# How do I move an sqlite database to a writable location for iOS?

Tags: python, ios, xcode, sqlite, kivy

I am bundling an application for `iOS` using `Python's Kivy framework`, and I have created my `.xcodeproj` and everything works fine when I push it to my iPhone, however when I do anything that writes to my SQLite database, my app crashes and I get the following error:

`...SQLite3.OperationsError:` attempt to write a readonly database

I read that you cannot write anything in the /Application directory and to instead use the /Library directory for databases, so I attempted to move my database there and got the following error:

IOError: [Errno 1] Operation is not permitted: `'/Library/user.db'`

Which is the same error I get if I try and list out the directory using

```
os.listdir('/Library')
```

So my question is, what is the best way to move my database from where it is currently at, to a writable directory?

Comment: you cannot right in the `ApplicationBundle`. There's a `document directory` in iOS where you can keep your writable files and data.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I can't use the document directory because I want the database hidden from the user. According to Apple,

Comment: Who said copying the `DataBase` to the `Documents Directory` will expose it to the user?

Comment: Sorry, accidently submitted my last answer midway through. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html
 says

Comment: Documents/ "Use this directory to store user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing; therefore, his directory should only contain files that you may wish to expose to the user. "

Comment: Also, I don't know the path to the documents directory even if I wanted to use it. I can list my working directory as 
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7C72EC29-D99F-42A5-9499-6A0D1FC4CE83/this_is_my_app.app/YourApp

and I can list out the root directory with os.listdir('/') which returns
['.Trashes', '.file', '.fseventsd', 'Applications', 'Developer', 'Library', 'System', 'bin', 'cores', 'dev', 'etc', 'private', 'sbin', 'tmp', 'usr', 'var'])
But I get an error for any other directory I try and list out saying "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get allowed path

```
path_to_your_database = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir
```

How said in documentation, it

> Returns the path to the directory in the users file system which the
>   application can use to store additional data.

Read more on [this page](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html?highlight=user_data_dir#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir)

Answer (score 0):

Solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/tvuesKUSb5g

Basically I did the following (Used /Library because it stores the database in a location that's not viewable to the user)

writable_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')+'/Library'

Problem was basically if you do:
print (os.path.expanduser('~'))

You'll get something like:

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F08D469E-56AB-4BF4-831E-E011E2632535/

At some point early on in my troubleshooting, I started statically assigning the directory and trying to list it out to figure out the directory structure.

os.listdir('/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F08D469E-56AB-4BF4-831E-E011E2632535/')

Which does not work because *F08D469E-56AB-4BF4-831E-E011E2632535* is a randomly generated value created each time you build your project. Once I switched to using my writable_dir variable, it worked fine.